# slideToggle opens and immediately closes under certain circumstances

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following to slideToggle() an element on my page:

```
$('body').on('click', '#commentArticle', function(e) {
    $('#commentArticleForm').slideToggle({
        duration: 400,
        step: resizeContentHeight
    });

});
```

The behaviour is not consistent. If you access the page directly ([here)](http://rlcoaching.com/hat/index.php?page=article.php?aid=1) and toggle the Post Comment form, it works as intended. **But if you go on the parent page ([here)](http://rlcoaching.com/hat/index.php?page=news.php) and click on the first article link (brings you to the same page) then about 90% of the time the form will toggle open and then close immediately.** Refreshing the page will correct the glitch.

I don't even know where to start to debug such an inconsistent behaviour, especially as the problem only happens sometimes when accessing the page from the parent page.

Please tell me if any more information is needed to help track down this glitch.

NB: Behaviour observed on Chrome, Firefox and Safari on OSX.

EDIT: By adding `console.log("a")` in the function above I now see where the problem comes from, when the `slideToggle()` goes "yo-yo" it's actually because a single click on `#commentArticle` for some reason gets recorded as two clicks, ie: console shows `a` twice.

Comment: I tried 4 to 5 times, traversing from parent page to 'My First Article'. It works fine..

Comment: @ArunBS That is definitely weird, I can guarantee I get it. Mind if I ask what OS? Edited the post with new info.

Comment: Windows. Checked in Chrome. This thread might help you -> stackoverflow.com/questions/8513870/how-to-stop-jquery-slidetoggle-yo-yo-resolved-even-more-resolved

Comment: @ArunBS Thanks that indeed helped, my script is getting loaded multiple times because of AJAX. Think I'll just have to load all scripts with main page instead of loading only what's needed through my AJAX calls. It will slow down the site loading but should prevent multiple bindings!

Answer (score 2):

I've had this exact problem and this is how I fixed it:

1) You need to add "touchstart" to the method for iPad. 
2) You need to add preventDefault to keep the tap from firing twice

```
$(document).on("click touchstart","'#commentArticle", function(e){
        $('#commentArticleForm').slideToggle({
            duration: 400,
            step: resizeContentHeight
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Please try it and see that it works.

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed.

Comment: I don't think additionally binding to the *touchstart* event will change anything

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your js file is included only once.